# PyKeyboard Fn Key Support

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keyboard

Does PyKeyboard support the <kbd>Fn</kbd> Key? I have looked at it and didn't seem to find an attrtibute that may refer to it or it is just that it had a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput/blob/master/pykeyboard/x11.py) might help you. It looks like it has support for function keys. What os are you running?

https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput Is this the package you are using?

Comment: yes that is the package I am using and I am using a Debian Linux